# uitableView dataset not working in my case

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

this is my code

```
class TableViewOne: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCell") as! firstCell
        let index = indexPath.row
        cell.labelMy.text = ViewController.firstData![index]
        return cell

    }

     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let s = ViewController.firstData {
            return s.count
        }
        return 0
    }

}
```

and in a UIViewControlelr i have this:

```
@IBOutlet var myTableView1: UITableView!
```

then in the view did load i say

```
let t1 = TableViewOne()

        myTableView1.delegate = t1
        myTableView1.dataSource = t1
```

however when i make

```
self.myTableView1.reloadData()
```

i put a break point at the begining of all the functions inside `TableViewOne` and no one fired at all

Comment: You don't appear to be keeping a strong reference to the `TableViewOne` instance.

Comment: @rmaddy well i don't know how to do that. should I just move the let t1=TableViewOne() to the out of view did load ?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use an instance variable.